# jquery.ui.tabs loads before jquery.ui.widget when using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, requirejs

I have this code in my main.js script, but I can't make it works with jQueryUI, because somehow when trying to load jQueryMobile, it always loads jquery.ui.tabs before jquery.ui.widget, with the latter being a dependency of the former

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    paths: {
        'libs'          : '../libs',
        'jquery'        : '../libs/jquery/jquery.min',
        'jquery-plugins'    : '../libs/jquery-mobile/external/jquery/plugins',
        'jquery-ui'     : '../libs/jquery-ui/ui',
        "jquery.ui.widget"  : '../libs/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.widget',
        'jquery.ui.tabs'    : '../libs/jquery-ui-tabs/ui/jquery.ui.tabs',
        'jquery-mobile'     : '../libs/jquery-mobile/js/',
        'backbone'      : '../libs/backbone/backbone',
        'underscore'        : '../libs/underscore/underscore',
        'json'              : '../libs/json2/json',
        'json2'         : '../libs/json2',
        'jstorage'      : '../libs/jstorage/jstorage.min',
        'mustache'      : '../libs/mustache'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'json': {
            exports:'JSON'
        },
        'jstorage':  ['jquery', 'json'],
        'mustache': {
            exports: 'Mustache'
        },
        'jquery-plugins'    : ['jquery'],
        'jquery.ui.widget'  : ['jquery', 'jquery.ui.core'],
        'jquery.ui.tabs'    : [ 'jquery' , 'jquery.ui.widget']
    }
});

require(['app'], function(App){
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function(){
        console.log('Evento mobileinit');
        App.initialize();
    });
})
```

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Console]

[image: Sources view]

Comment: Maybe you need to shim the widget too?

Comment: Please edit into your question the errors you get on the console. If you don't get any errors on the console, please indicate this in your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it ASAP, just can't do it right now

Comment: Thread has been updated with screenshots and modifications to the loader script.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't specified the path to `'jquery.ui.core'` which is listed as a dependency of `'jquery.ui.widget'`.

Comment: Ok, let me try that and I'll post feedback

Comment: It doesn't work either. And the network inspector gives http 200 OK when loading it. As I said before, problem is that it gets loaded after jquery.ui.tabs